# Can abbreviations be used as stand-alone adjectives when the abbreviated term couldn't?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, abbreviations, modifiers

> I see by your name that you are probably ESL...

*ESL* stands for "English as a second language". In the above sentence, it is being used as a stand-alone adjective, but I'm not sure if that makes sense. The term would not work as an adjective if it wasn't abbreviated, as in:

> I see by your name that you are probably English as a second language...

You can be *English as a second language*, that's absurd. However, *ESL* is used like an adjective (or a modifier, I'm not quite sure on the terminology), in cases like *ESL writer* or *ESL speaker*. If it modifying the noun, and modifiers are usually adjectives or adverbs. Because of that, it seems that perhaps it would be correct to use this abbreviation as a stand-alone adjective in the example sentence. Or is this ungrammatical?

Comment: In 'football manager', 'football' is used as a premodifier, but is not an adjective. You wouldn't say "Are you football?" except in very informal, telescoped usage (eg "I know that in your school, you have to choose to do either football or rugby. Are you football?" [= "Are you one of the pupils who chose football?"] ) But this is also true of many examples with adjectives ("I know that your family always have blue or grey eyes. Are you blue?")

Comment: For some it's obligatory. _Mrs._ has a pronunciation /'mɪsəz/ and an abbreviated spelling, with a period. But no original, except _Mistress_, which is never used any more.